# Regarding Extract Function

Tags: mumps

i have query related to extract function, will Extract Function accept ASCII Value?

Answer (score 4):

The $EXTRACT function when given a string of ASCII characters, will return a substring of that string.
for example $EXTRACT("Hello World",1,6) is "Hello"

If you want to extract the ASCII value of a character in a string, use the function $ASCII.

If you want to create a string given the ASCII values, use the function $CHAR.

For example $EXTRACT("ABC",2) is "B"  and $ASCII("ABC",2) is the number 66
and the function $CHAR(67,65,66) is the string "CAB".